# Get all tags from GitHub repository

Tags: rest, github, get, github-api, git-tag

I use GitHub api, that described here: [GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags)

The command looks like:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/tags
```

But this command **get only last 30 tags**.

Is it possible to receive **all** tags from GitHub repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting trolled by pagination:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#pagination

API responses contain links to fetch other pages of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely pagination as [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26806353/107840) indicates.  The default pagination is 30 per page.  You can tweak this to return up to 100 per page, by passing in the `per_page` parameter.

Although there is no API command to return all records at once, I would recommend looking at [how the GitHub ruby client implements](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/13efb0c7acc64ec828a344f3e5b4087f33078476/lib/octokit/connection.rb#L86-L94) its `auto_paginate` feature and/or [the oktokit.js paginate method](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#example-using-the-octokitjs-pagination-method) and/or [the API documentation regarding a custom js pagination implementation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#example-creating-a-pagination-method).

I'll use the ruby client implementation as an example.  It defaults to the standard pagination, but this can be overridden by calling `client.auto_paginate = true`

When `auto_paginate` is true and pagination is applied to a given endpoint, the client will:

1. Set `per_page` to the max of 100
2. Fetch the first 100
3. If the response contains header links to `rel['next']`, it means there's another page to fetch.
4. Continue fetching while there are more pages AND you have not reached the API rate limit (typically, 5000 per hour)

Note, you can check your rate limit status by calling the `https://api.github.com/rate_limit` endpoint and checking `rate.remaining`.  If you hit the limit, you will get an error and need to wait until the `rate.reset` time.